# Get yum list installed in a array variable BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am writing a BASH script
i want the list of installed software (example yum) in a array variable

I tried this

```
info=($(yum list installed | grep 'yum'))
```

so when i am looping through ${info[@]}.  result is a single element with all yum packages

```
for soft in "${info[*]}"
  do
    echo $soft
    echo "hello \n"
  done
```

Example

```
(yum.noarch 1.xxx.centos @base yum-utils.noarch 1.xxx.centos @base yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch 1.xxx.centos @base)

hello \n
```

What i want is info will have 3 element instead of one

```
(
yum.noarch 1.xxx.centos @base,
yum-utils.noarch 1.xxx.centos @base,
yum-plugin-fastestmirror.noarch 1.xxx.centos @base 

)
```

How do i get these yum list in a array objects

Comment: `so when i am looping through ${info[@]}. result is a single element with all yum` Most probably there is an error in the way your loop is written..

Comment: i have added my for loop code snipet

Comment: `"${info[*]}"` -> `"${info[@]}"`

Comment: thanks its now giving me multiple element but each column in list command also an  element here.  Example (yum.noarch ,  1.xxx.centos,  @base, yum-utils.noarch , 1.xxx.centos ,  @base).  basically i want 3 element as mentioned in question

Comment: See the answer below. You may want to research "word splitting" expansion and `IFS` variable.

Comment: Is wild card supported for `yum` ? , with `rpm` instead of `rpm -qa | grep kernel` you could do `rpm -qa \*kernel\*` it works the same without the pipe and `grep`

Answer (score 0):

To read data into an array separating with newlines, use `readarray`. To redirect input from a command to `readarray`, use *redirection* with *process substitution*.

```
readarray -t info < <(yum list installed | grep 'yum')
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.net .